What happens to core dump when pid is reused
When using the core dump management system called systemd-coredump we can see the list of core dumps with coredumpctl list.
The list of core dumps is listed with date and pid.
To extract the actual core file one has to do this command:
coredumpctl dump <pid> --output /tmp/mycore.core.
Note how the command to extract only accepts pid.
What happens when the pid is eventually reused?   That is, how would coredumpctl know which core file to extract?
Note: I am anticipating at least one person will tell me this is unlikely.  Unfortunately a 1 in a billion thing happens often on computers.


Note how the command to extract only accepts pid.

That's not correct. It also accepts executable paths and raw journalctl filters, as documented in its manual page.
Each core dump is recorded as a system log message in the journal (with various metadata fields that don't show up in plain journalctl) and <pid> is only one of several documented shortcuts for a search filter.

What happens when the pid is eventually reused? That is, how would coredumpctl know which core file to extract?

coredumpctl uses the most recent dump it finds. (As the manual page says, "dump: Extract the last core dump matching specified characteristics.")
If you want to extract an older dump and the PIDs do collide, you can additionally specify the executable path as a filter:
coredumpctl info 1234 ~/a.out

If they still collide, you'll need the manual way of extracting – the coredumpctl info will show you all matching entries, each with its Storage: field:
           PID: 2707033 (tracker-extract)
       Storage: /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.trac[...].zst (present)

which you can uncompress with:
sudo zstdcat /var/..zst > foo.core

Alternatively (the slightly harder way) is to do a coredumpctl --json which will show you the raw timestamp of each dump, and access them like this:
coredumpctl info COREDUMP_TIMESTAMP=1711698146000000

Alternatively (the more harder way) is to start with this filter for journalctl (which I got from SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug coredumpctl info 1234):
journalctl -o verbose MESSAGE_ID=fc2e22bc6ee647b6b90729ab34a250b1 COREDUMP_PID=1234

(really this is enough)
journalctl -o verbose COREDUMP_PID=1234

and once you scroll through the heaps of text to find the specific dump you want, you can select it with:
coredumpctl info COREDUMP_TIMESTAMP=1711698146000000


Unfortunately a 1 in a billion thing happens often on computers.

This is not entirely a chance thing, as PIDs are not assigned randomly; they are a counter that is incremented for each process (and most Linux systems that run systemd are set up to have 222 PIDs). So as long as the system keeps running, PIDs won't start getting reused at all until the counter rolls over, which will likely take a good two months on a typical PC.
Rebooting and therefore resetting the PID counter is the primary way that would happen – PIDs start from 1 on every boot, so if it's a system service that crashes, then the chance of the same crashing service always getting the same PID across multiple boots can actually be fairly high.
(Well, low on modern parallel-boot systems, but on an embedded device it can even be as high as "100% guaranteed".)
PID reuse was much more common with older configurations that used a maximum of 216 which was just 65536 and could roll over simply during a long compile or whatever.
